# Event handler cause problem when i force application quit

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that captures word events. In this macro in the Document_Open event, I'm going to show the dialog box and force word to quit. With the latest update, the exit instruction causes me a serious error that is shown to me when I go to recall the same document. If I delete the Word close statement and do it manually everything works fine.
I tried different solutions but could not solve the problem.
I use Word 365 .

This is the event class where i call the routine and then close the document and quit from Word.

```
Public WithEvents App As Application


Private Sub App_DocumentOpen(ByVal Doc As Document)

   StampaModulo
   
   Doc.Close False
   App.Quit
    
End Sub
```

This is the module where in AutoExec I associate the application with the class.

```
Dim x As New EventClassHandler

Public Sub AutoExec()
    Set x.App = Application
End Sub
```

When I open the same word document, the document is in the disativated element and I receive this message.

[image: img error message]

[image: img disativated element]

[image: word version]

I tried also to force the quit in the routine of the print of the word document but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

At last I have found another user out there reporting the same, absolutely weird behavior of Word 365 when using Application.quit, thanks a lot! And you confirm our suspicion that a Windows or Office update must have caused this condition, as it suddenly started to happen on all our clients in January 2023.

We are using Word 365 MSO, the current version is 2212 (Build 16.0.15928.20278) 32 Bit.
This issue only happens in modules of our Word macro which do standalone processes like printing and finally close the opened Word instance by executing **Application.quit**, same as yours. And never had been a problem before. In all other circumstances, the user closes the document and Word manually to finish his work.

The Application.quit method of this version apparently kills the Word instance without taking care of its dependent components like the document, its template, global templates in the autostart path as well as the macro. The cause for this issue obviously is a **time and latency problem**. I found a **workaround** by adding a waiting loop (using Sleep and DoEvents) just before executing the Application.Quit method. By several attempts I could reduce the necessary time of the waiting loop to 2 - 3 seconds.

But I don't really like this type of solution, as waiting loops are too uncertain, too shaky, always a gamble. But up to now, unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution to check the dependent components to be safely closed and/or unloaded.

Comment: I wrote to Microsoft support where they confirmed it to be a probable bug in the latest version of Word. They advised me to open a report directly with the development team, which I did. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next version. For now, since few customers use this macro, I've removed the force quit Word and customers manually close Word after printing.

Comment: **Good News:** After an automatic Office Update on my notebook by our IT departement yesterday afternoon, the described behaviour from above seems to be gone! My Word 365 now shows Version 2301 Build 16.0.16026.20214 (32 Bit)